# jQuery.lightbox : youtube videos?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm able to apply a JQuery.lightbox to an image but how do I apply it to a youtube video?

```
<script src="jquery.lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
...
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) :
    $kids = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    $attributes = $kids->group->content[0]->attributes();
    $flv = $attributes['url'];
    $attributes = $kids->group->player->attributes();
    $link = $attributes['url']; 
?>
<a rel="lightbox" href="<?=$link?>" title="youtube video title">
 <img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/<?=$id?>/default.jpg" />
</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this quick tutorial on how to create a lightbox effects for youtube videos !

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92c3dX-AoXs

Hope this helps :)